# QT hangs my toolbar and its buttons

Tags: qt, qwidget

I've created 2 classes, each:

1. has `QWidget` as a parent
2. has `Q_OBJECT` macros
3. inits some actions, creates menubar and toolbar, and connects actions to them

Then I created the main program file, created `QMainWindow`, and init my two classes by `qmainwnd` pointer.

And what I've got - menu works, the second toolbar works, but the first toolbar (created by class 1) doesn't respond to mouse clicks.

What happed with it? Why I can not even move this first toolbar or click its buttons?

Here a sample:

[main.cpp](http://pastebin.com/Qu7ibFqy)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>

#include "CModDocument.h"
#include "CModEditor.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow wnd;

    // init CA
    CModDocument a(&wnd);

    // init CB
    CModEditor b(&wnd);

    wnd.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[CModDocument.h](http://pastebin.com/XQwnjv8V)

```
#ifndef CMODDOCUMENT_H
#define CMODDOCUMENT_H

#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QAction;
class QToolBar;
class QMainWindow;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class CModDocument: public QWidget
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CModDocument(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QMainWindow *getMainWnd();

public slots:
    void newFile();
    void open();
    bool save();
    bool saveAs();

private:
    void createActions();
    void createToolBars();
    void interCom();

    QMainWindow *mainWnd;

    QToolBar *fileToolBar;
    QAction *newAct;
    QAction *openAct;
    QAction *saveAct;
    QAction *saveAsAct;
};

#endif // CMODDOCUMENT_H
```

[CModDocument.cpp](http://pastebin.com/3unqywPk)

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDebug>
#include "CModDocument.h"

CModDocument::CModDocument( QWidget *parent )
: QWidget( parent )
, mainWnd( (QMainWindow*)parent )
{
    createActions();
    createToolBars();
    interCom();

    mainWnd->statusBar()->showMessage(tr("Ready"));
}

void CModDocument::newFile()
{
    qDebug() << "newFile";
}

void CModDocument::open()
{
    qDebug() << "open";
}

bool CModDocument::save()
{
    qDebug() << "save";
    bool retVal;
    return retVal;
}

bool CModDocument::saveAs()
{
    qDebug() << "saveAs";
    bool retVal;
    return retVal;
}


void CModDocument::createActions()
{
    newAct = new QAction(tr("&New"), this);
    newAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::New);
    newAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));

    openAct = new QAction(tr("&Open..."), this);
    openAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Open);
    openAct->setStatusTip(tr("Open an existing file"));

    saveAct = new QAction(tr("&Save"), this);
    saveAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Save);
    saveAct->setStatusTip(tr("Save the document to disk"));

    saveAsAct = new QAction(tr("Save &As..."), this);
    saveAsAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::SaveAs);
    saveAsAct->setStatusTip(tr("Save the document under a new name"));
}

void CModDocument::createToolBars()
{
    fileToolBar = mainWnd->addToolBar(tr("File"));
    fileToolBar->addAction(newAct);
    fileToolBar->addAction(openAct);
    fileToolBar->addAction(saveAct);
}

void CModDocument::interCom()
{
    connect(newAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));
    connect(openAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(open()));
    connect(saveAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(save()));
    connect(saveAsAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(saveAs()));
}
```

[CModEditor.h](http://pastebin.com/8pxjvY66)

```
#ifndef CMODEDITOR_H
#define CMODEDITOR_H

#include <QWidget>
// #include "CModEdiWidget.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QMainWindow;
class QAction;
class QMenu;
class QMenuBar;
class QToolBar;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class CModEditor : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CModEditor(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void cut();

private:
    void createActions();
    void createToolBars();
    void interCom();

    QAction *cutAct;
    QToolBar *editToolBar;

    // parent
    QMainWindow *mainWnd;
};

#endif
```

[CModEditor.cpp](http://pastebin.com/0qqVZTMx)

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDebug>

#include "CModEditor.h"

CModEditor::CModEditor(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
, mainWnd( (QMainWindow*)parent )
{
    createActions();
    createToolBars();
    interCom();
}

void CModEditor::cut()

{
    qDebug() << "cut";
}
void CModEditor::createActions()
{
    cutAct = new QAction(tr("Cu&t"), this);
    cutAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Cut);
    cutAct->setStatusTip(tr("Cut the current selection's contents to the clipboard"));
}

void CModEditor::createToolBars()
{
    editToolBar = mainWnd->addToolBar(tr("Edit"));
    editToolBar->addAction(cutAct);
    editToolBar->setIconSize(QSize(16, 16));
}

void CModEditor::interCom()
{
    connect(cutAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(cut()));
}
```

[build.pro](http://pastebin.com/FsQeFXis)

```
CONFIG      -= app_bundle
HEADERS         = CModDocument.h   CModEditor.h
SOURCES         = CModDocument.cpp CModEditor.cpp main.cpp
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear at the moment and you give us way too little information to answer it. Can you produce a (very minimal) example code that exhibits this problem? Or at least clarify your question?

Comment: In its current form this question isn't really answerable. I think you need to expand this question with some code samples so we can see what you're doing. When you've done this feel free to flag and have it re-opened. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, here a sample: [CModDocument.cpp](http://pastebin.com/3unqywPk), [CModDocument.h](http://pastebin.com/XQwnjv8V), [CModEditor.cpp](http://pastebin.com/0qqVZTMx), [CModEditor.h](http://pastebin.com/8pxjvY66), [main.cpp](http://pastebin.com/Qu7ibFqy), [build.pro](http://pastebin.com/FsQeFXis)

Comment: The one way to solve the problem I'v found is to change `QWidget` to `QObject` - so the program starts to work. **`QWidget`** as a parent seems a **bad** thing. But the code above with `QWidget` so you can reproduce an interface 'hang up'.

Comment: You haven't added sample code here, you've added links to sample code. please post the relevant bits _within_ your question, indent four spaces to the right for code formatting.

Comment: Would you reopened my question please? Some research of **qt** source codes, moc-generated files needed to get the source of a problem - the  difference between `QObject` and `QWidget` when using them for sub-classing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to configure the `QMainWindow` as the parent to two `QWidget`s. I modified your `main()` function as follows and it worked:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow wnd;

    QWidget w;

    // init CA
    CModDocument a(&wnd, &w);

    // init CB
    CModEditor b(&wnd, &w);

    wnd.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Notice the new `QWidget w` that parents `a` and `b`. I'm not even sure my approach is adequate (it probably isn't). I think it is better to add a `QLayout` to `w` and add `a` and `b` to that `QLayout`. Then you could set `w` as `wnd`'s central widget.